# How to set a ForeignKey field while .save() data from API in views.py

Tags: python, database, model

I am pulling data from an api and trying to save it directly into my db from views although I keep getting an error because I have to choose the ForeignKey field.

How can I do this in the .save() function?

```py
    views.py

    all_teams = {}
    teams = Teams()
    for team in teams:
        team_list = Team(
            name=team.name,
            abbreviation=team.abbreviation,
            league= <--- ForiegnKey Field
        )
        team_list.save()
```

```py
    models.py
       
    class League(models.Model):
    LEAGUES = (
        ('MLB', ('MLB')),
        ('NBA', ('NBA')),
        ('NCAAB', ('NCAAB')),
        ('NFL', ('NFL')),
    )

    name = models.CharField(
        max_length=10, choices=LEAGUES, null=False, blank=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


    class Team(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=False, blank=False)
    abbreviation = models.CharField(max_length=10, null=False, 
    blank=False)
    league = models.ForeignKey(
        'League', null=False, blank=False, 
         on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Updated Answer:**
You have created the model for the Leagues, both no object has been created. To put it in lay-mans terms, you have the blueprints but there is no building yet.

In order to create an object for the league, you need add the following in your views.py above the code for creating teams.

```
mlb = League.objects.create(name='MLB')
```

Updated Views.py

```
mlb = League.objects.create(name='MLB')
all_teams = {}
    teams = Teams()
    for team in teams:
        team_list = Team(
            name=team.name,
            abbreviation=team.abbreviation,
            league=mlb
        )
        team_list.save()
```

Additionally, please make the following change in your models.py, remove the quotes around League.

Your Code:

```
class Team(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=False, blank=False)
    abbreviation = models.CharField(max_length=10, null=False, 
    blank=False)
    league = models.ForeignKey(
        'League', null=False, blank=False, 
         on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Updated Version:

```
class Team(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=False, blank=False)
    abbreviation = models.CharField(max_length=10, null=False, 
    blank=False)
    league = models.ForeignKey(
        League, null=False, blank=False, 
         on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

**Original Answer:**

> Please share your code for models.py and views.py entirely so that I
> can help you better. Making a few assumptions I have answered your
> question below.
>
> You first need to create a new object for the FOREIGN KEY, in you case
> a new league object. `python premier_league = League.objects.create(name='Permier')`
>
> Then you can use this when creating a new team
>
> ````py
>     name=team.name,
>     abbreviation=team.abbreviation,
>     league=permier_league ) team_list.save() ```
> ````

Comment: Updated. Thanks for your help!

Comment: And I don't need to create a new one. I need to select current ones.

Comment: Sure no problem, please mark the answer as accepted to help me out, have a great day!